# c++ Boost-asio static libraries to release static compilation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, lib

I created a TCP C++ communication app using VS and Boost-Asio library. 
It works fine if compiled with to Debug option.

But my client requires the executable to contain all the necessary libraries so I have to compile in Release and with static libraries.

And when I do this I get the following error:

Error LNK1104 can not open file 'libboost_system-vc141-mt-**s**-1_64.lib'

In the libraries folder of the boost there is the file:

'Libboost_system-vc141-mt-1_64.lib'

I imagine this different  **s** is from **s**tatic libraries.

Does anyone know how I can create them since all of these boost libs are created by b2 and bjam in the installation.

Comment: If I remember correctly `-s-` is for statically-linked runtime. You should add `runtime-link=static` to b2 command when building boost.

Comment: I will try. Thank you.